# No retraction $r\colon \mathbb{RP}^n\to\mathbb{RP}^k$ for $n>k>0$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Here is my question:

> No retraction $r\colon \mathbb{RP}^n\to\mathbb{RP}^k$ for $n>k>0$.

Here is my attempt, with a question:

Suppose there were a retraction $r\colon\mathbb{RP}^n\to\mathbb{RP}^k$. By definition, we then have an inclusion $i\colon\mathbb{RP}^k\to\mathbb{RP}^n$ such that $r\circ i=\text{Id}$. By functoriality, $i^\ast\circ r^\ast=(r\circ i)^\ast=\text{id}^\ast$, where $r^\ast\colon H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)\to H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{F}_2)$, $i^\ast\colon H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{F}_2)\to H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)$, and $\text{Id}^\ast\colon H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)\to H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is the trivial/identity automorphism. This implies $r^\ast$ is injective. Note that $H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[\beta]/(\beta^{k+1})$ with $\beta\in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)$ a generator, and $H^\ast(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[\alpha]/(\alpha^{n+1})$ with $\alpha\in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{F}_2)$ a generator. Since it's a ring homomorphism $r^\ast(\beta)=\alpha$ and $r^\ast(0)=0$. Therefore
$$
0=r^\ast(0)=r^\ast(\beta^{k+1})=r^\ast(\beta)^{k+1}=\alpha^{k+1}.
$$
But $\alpha^{k+1}\neq0$ since $k+1<n+1$ and $|\alpha|=n+1$, a contradiction.

Here is my question: I don't see where I used that $r^\ast$ is injective.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\beta$ maps to $\alpha$ under $r^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the level of the first cohomology, the map $r^*$ takes $\beta$ to $\alpha$ because $r^*$ is injective.

Infact using similar reasoning as yours, one can conclude that there is no continuous map $f: \mathbb{RP}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^k$ such that the map induced at the level of first cohomology (with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ coefficients) is non trivial.

Comment: Could you explain the first part a bit more. There is some general algebra going on that I am not getting. The map $r^\ast$ is a map on the cohomology *ring*, so how can you speak of it as a map on the first cohomology *group*?

Comment: $r^*$ is a priori a map on the groups. Later one checks that it descends to a map of the cohomology ring. Or you can think of the map $r^*$ as being a graded ring homomorphism.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what it is: $\beta\in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^k;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\alpha\in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong\mathbb{F}_2$ are generators so represent the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_2$, so now that $r^\ast$ is injective homomorphism it can't map $\beta$ to $0$, so it has to map to $\alpha$...?

Comment: Yes. That is the main idea.